# Does modeling entity-relationship using SQL Server built-in "Diagrams" have performance benefits on the execution of queries?

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-relationship

As database designing go I have never modeled the relationships of my tables by way of SQL Server diagrams, drawing how two or more tables are related using their primary and foreign keys. I am using Entity Framework and LINQ and for the most part I write the queries in code and that seems to be fine.

So my question is will it make execution of my queries faster if I do SQL Server diagrams? Does it help the database engine at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.**

The SQL Server diagrams are merely graphical representations of your database structure. Using the diagrams instead of using raw T-SQL to create your tables has **no impact whatsoever** on runtime behavior or performance. In the end, the tables, views, constraints etc. are all the same - whether done via diagrams or via raw T-SQL commands....

Answer (score 0):

Diagrams in Entity Framework are for visual Representation only. you form the Relationship in SQL Server or Entity Framework and apply it Database does the same. **EF is a layer of Abstraction in top of ADO.NET**. So it is always **slower** when compared to regular ADO.NET.